# How can I switch to pop up facebook sign up page in Selenium?

Tags: facebook, selenium-webdriver, switch-statement, popupwindow

I am not able to switch to pop up facebook sign up page using selenium.Tried switch to method but still not working.
[FB Signup page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKx29.png)

Tried below code

```
public void createNewAccount() {
    

    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Create new account")).click();
    
    for (String currentWindow: driver.getWindowHandles())
           driver.switchTo().window(currentWindow);

    driver.findElement(By.name("firstname")).sendKeys("Black");
    
    driver.findElement(By.name("lastname")).sendKeys("Beard");
```

But its not letting me to write any text in the textbo.

Comment: First off you are only allowed one Facebook account. Secondly Facebook doesn't allow you to interact with their website programmatically.

Comment: that's just a modal div... no need to switch the driver to it.  Right-click on it and choose "Inspect" to find the element(s) you need to target.  (It's been a while, but last I checked FB doesn't seem to block bots much at all...)

Comment: @browsermator, I have also tried the way that you mentioned. but not able to get the textbox for the Name field.